# Good javaScript time picker which shows previous and next time option?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

Hi I am looking for a JavaScript time picker which shows the previous and next option. The closest one I found is [eonasdan's Boostrap 3 time picker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#bootstrap-3-datepicker-v4-docs)! But the thing missing is the visible previous/next time option. I did a mock up picture and highlighted the fields that I need in orange based on eonasdan's solution but I have no clue how to make it. Is there any good time picker I can use to make it?

[image]

Comment: What you have to do is hack the library and put your desired modifications in there, unless you find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://github.com/CuriousSolutions/DateTimePicker). In this you are provided with Date, Time and Date and Time together.

Comment: this doesn't answer the OP's question